# linux script to test connectivity IP

Tags: linux

Any idea how to create a script in order to test connectivity with IP that represents a default gateway. And in case of connectivity, to print the message "Default gateway up" and if it's not connected to give a message "Default gateway down"

Comment: You should pick the answer you feel responds to your question so that the person who replied can have the reputation awarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash 
ping -c 1 192.168.1.1 2>&1 > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then 
       echo -e "host does not respond to ping" 
fi
```

Put this script in crontab and let it run every min or whatever frequency you want.